# Visual Studio Web Performance Think Time is not working on web services calls

Tags: visual-studio, web-performance

I have a problem with Visual Studio Web Performance test. In one web service I need to wait 30 seconds but when I set the think time to 30 at the properties of the web service call it doesn't wait.

I have tried to set the think time to 30000 but I notice not difference when I run the test.

Here is the list of properties that I have for that web request:

- Cache Control: False
- Encoding: utf-8
- Expected Http Status Code: 0
- Expected Response URL:
- Follow Redirects: True
- Record Results: True
- Reporting name:
- Response Time Goal: 0
- Think Time(seconds): 30
- Timeout(seconds): 300
- Method: POST
- Version 1.1

Also I tired to set the think time to 3000 and the timeout to 300 and the test keep not waiting and finished the execution without any issue.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Check whether the "Think Profile" is set to "on": on the scenario https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406966.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997697.aspx

Comment: Think times take place **after** the request is processed. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562687/how-to-delay-execution-of-the-first-request-of-a-web-test) for a related discussion. You question may be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @jessehouwing Currently my issue is present on the web performance part, I am not even creating a load test. I will have your answer in mind when I start doing the load test.

At the end I created a custom validation rule